# How to setup a C development environment on Linux for GTK+?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, libs

I'm new to programming C in Linux. I like to make GUIs with GTKlibs. The only problem is that im unable - and not only with gtk - to install these packages correctly. I have problem to include the librarys like `#include<gtk/gtk.h>` if I have installed it with `sudo apt-get install gtklib-3-dev`.

On compile time it sais everytime that the file is missing and so on. I have read the option to put dpkg configs and cflags to the compiler, but that doesn`t work either. How linux is managing the include folder and why do libs like gtk have an upperfolder with the version on it like gtk3 etc.. This is the problem that leads to missing files.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried. A description does not give enough information. We need the exact commands you use and the exact error message. Please also read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The upper folder name is so that one can install multiple versions simultaneously gtk2 / gtk3 and not run into conflicts.

Comment: gcc at compile time manages which include folders to use with -I flags. In this way one can pick gtk2 or gtk3 when both are installed. For libraries with a .pc file you can use pkg-config to get them: `pkg-config gtk+-3 --cflags-only-I`. At link time similar calls are needed for the libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact package name depends on your Linux distribution. If you're using Ubuntu, then the right command is:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

You may then check if the development packages are detected with something like:

```
pkg-config --exists gtk+-3.0 && echo "Installed" || echo "Not installed"
```

To learn how to build your application, follow the instructions of the official documentation on [How to compile GTK+ applications](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-compiling.html).

Finally, instead of doing the gcc calls manualy, you can automate them by using a build system like the [Meson build system](http://mesonbuild.com/). There's a tutorial on how to [build a simple GTK+ application with Meson](http://mesonbuild.com/Tutorial.html).

Comment: Note that not all development packages will be so considerate as to package a .pc file for pkg-config in which case the above call may give false negatives. For gtk the above is safe.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, i have tried it many times with pkg-config.
At the moment i tried:

gcc -Wall -std=c11 'pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0' ./main.c -o main 'pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0' and it gives me the error: 
gcc: error: no such file or directory.

i have tried it only with the single command pkg-config and it shows the path similar to the documentation.

Comment: Can someone explain me the background stuff about the package system or how the gcc are looking for and link packages. Or maybe a link. The documentations are less helpfull, because often they show too specific stuff.

Comment: This is a different question, and you should do some search on how to install packages on your system, and how to know which package provides which file. For now, check `gcc` is installed using `which gcc` (`man which` for details). Then you did a frequent mistake, you should use [backquote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) instead of single quotes. Those don't have the same measing in a shell. Replace the backquotes with the $(...) syntax, less error-prone. Thus, try `gcc -Wall -std=c11 $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) ./main.c -o main $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)`

Comment: omg, thank you so much. This does the Trick. I have tried it with backquote few weeks earlier, but no difference. Tried it no with the dollar and backquote and it compiles without errors and Warnings.